# Socket.io crash when psiphon3 is runningg in client machine

Tags: proxy, socket.io

I'm working on a traditional `php` web app to make it real-time using `socket.io`.

Every thing works fine except that now I did run `psiphon3`, for test my app behaviour with different `ip addresses` and to change my ip address.

I figured it out that socket.io would not react to requests from a machine that have psiphon3 running on it.

It seems all requests are in a queue and just when I stop psiphon3 in client computer, requests will come up to my server.

Do you know why is that?

I think it's because psiphon3 use different sockets for proxy tunnel and if this is the point, how can I figure out which user is using psiphon3 -`or may be another programms like this`- and how should I face these kind of programms?

**Thanks in Advance**